# Find the volume of the body that is created by these intervals

Tags: rotations, volume

Find the volume of the body that is created by the rotation of these intervals

$$0\leq x \leq {\pi\over 2}$$
$$0\leq y \leq (e^t\times sin(t))$$

I have no idea on where to begin or even know how to do this, I don't want an answer directly but please give me a direction on what to do to solve this problem, I don't really understand the question.

Am I supposed to create a function of these two and then add them together using the disc or shell method?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact problem phrasing? What is the axis of rotation for the volume? What is $t$?

Comment: @Martigan Exact phrasing is "Find the volume of the body that is created by rotating the areas (The intervals I gave before) around the x-axis"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $t$ is fixed, this area is a rectangle with one side on the $x$-axis. Rotation a rectangle around one of its sides generates a cylinder. The radius of the base of this cylinder is the side lying on the $y$-axis, and the height is the side lying on the $x$-axis.